# How to add custom menu opton in Tinymce in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-rails

I am using `tinymce-rails` gem for Tinymce and I want to add custom menu option. Right now I am doing what is suggested in the `readme` of gem like:

```
<%= f.input :content , :label => false ,  :placeholder => 'Content', input_html: {class: "tinymce"} %>
<%= tinymce %>
```

I am using `simple-form`.

I want to add a drop-down in the editor with a bunch of options (I have an array of names) and when user clicks on an option then the selected name should be inserted in the view of editor. And those names will be dynamic.

I tried to pass many options to the initialiser `tinymce` but unable to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the default initiator from the gem you could initiate tinymce manually and create the menu item at the same time:

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/menuitem.php

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '.my-class textarea',
        toolbar: "styleselect | bold italic | mybutton",
        setup: function(editor) {
        <% @my_items.each_with_index do |name, index| %>
            editor.addMenuItem('<%= name %>', {
                text: '<%= name %>',
                context: 'tools',
                onclick: function() {
                    editor.insertContent('<%= name %>');
                }
            <%= index == (@my_items.count - 1) ? '});' : '}),' %>
        < % end %>   
    });
</script>
```

We use a ternary operator to choose the correct closing tag based on the index of the names.

Theoretically you can also do this in the **config/tinymce.yml** file, but due to the dynamic nature it's not really plausible.

Something else you may want to look into is passing the menu to the activeEditor like:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.get('my_menu')
```

Comment: Thanks a lit Allan, but I wanted something similar to that option (with rails initialiser) because I am using editor in 4-5 different places and I want menu options on few places conditionally. If I use this then I have to write massive code in my views which I generally don't prefer. Is there a any other work around?

Comment: You could define a function like this in you jquery assets and call it with your params.  
Alternatively another good option would be a js.erb partial that you could call where necessary with your params.  I'll mock it up for you when I get the chance.